# NTFS Partition is mounted as read-only

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, read-only

I have 2 disks in my system, a primary SSD with Ubuntu installed in it(Firstly, I had windows recently switched to Ubuntu (first-boot))
I also have an internal HDD but it is mounted as a read-only device.
And it is partitioned into 2 drives (D-Drive and Work Drive) both are recognized as a read-only drive
I want to make read-write and executable
Please help!!

Comment: You should have disabled Windows Fast Startup before nuking it.

Comment: IF you don't still have Windows, THEN try `ntfsfix` on the two partitions. See `man ntfsfix` for more info.

Comment: The ntfsfix worked for me, but I had to unfortunately switch from Ubuntu 21.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Version. ntfsfix command didn't worked at all in 21.04 .... Thanks for your help 

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn off "fast startup" when you dual boot with Windows. Otherwise when you shut down Windows, it doesn't actually shut down. Fast startup is a hybrid suspend.

When Windows is suspended, it can place a lock on your storage and other hardware which will prevent you from being able to use them when you boot Ubuntu.